# Better way to truncate all entries of a Salesforce Object through API

Tags: apex, rest-api, api, metadata-api, bulk-api

I want to recreate all entries of a Custom object from external source everyday. Currently I am using BULK API and if I need to do a full refresh, I follow the following steps:

1. Query Id of all objects X (1 Bulk API with Query operation)
2. Delete all objects for X (1 Bulk API with Delete operation)
3. Create new objects for X (1 Bulk API with insert operation)

Is there any simple way to combine Step 1 and 2 as below:

```
https://mydomain.salesforce.com/api/Sobject/X/Truncate_All
```

**Note:**

- Object X has entries more than 1 million entries and I am following this flush and create approach since capturing the deltas and updating them specifically complicates my design.
- Upsert will not solve the problem since there can be deletion as well

Comment: Just FYI: there's an Idea for this (which confirms it's not possible): https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000k98UAAQ

Comment: well, have you tried to screenscrape it? I know it would hard to workaround CSRF issues in screenscraping...